# How to import svg file with same thickness

Tags: svg

I'm trying to make an animation using svg art I've designed before hand, but when I import it into blender the thickness of the lines are all the same. I know you can change their thickness but there's about 200+ lines/paths I'd need to edit for them to be right.

Is there a way you can think of to have them import with the correct thickness, or make their thickness all become correct once imported?

If you need more info on what I'm trying to do just ask.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "line thickness" in Blender; Blender is a 3D modelling software, not a 2D Illustration or Graphic design application.

Only way I see you can simulate a stroke in Blender is using beveling either through a simple *Bevel Depth* or through a *Bevel Object*

You batch set *Bevel Objects* for more than one curve at a time by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking the field or the picker icon, or you can copy the from an object to others by right clicking and choosing the option *Copy to Selected*.

If possible join all curves into one single object and then assign the *Bevel Object* in a single step, otherwise manually assign one by one.

You can just draw a simple straight line segment curve object and assign it as bevel object to simulate a "flat thickness". You can control final thickness per vertex by changing the per-vertex radius property.

Otherwise, if you don't mind a 3D-like circular-section bevel, you could just select all objects with the same thickness and bevel all curves simply with the desired *Bevel Depth*. This property can be batch assigned to all selected objects by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking the value button.

Alternatively you can [convert stroke thickness to path in Inkscape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169615/svg-contour-style-is-missing) and import it as actual geometry, at the expensive of editability and ease of working with the curves.

Comment: Mmm Yeah It seems that's the only way right now, I'll import the final image as a background, then import the SVG file to get the paths, then go through all of them and set the right thickness for each. Once that's done the animation will be dead easy. 
Good idea to batch bevel ones that have the same thickness to make it easier. 
Gonna need some tunes for this XD Thanks for answering though.