# Giving thickness to a line

Tags: modifiers, edges

In 2D-space I have this simple line consisting of three vertices connected by two edges.

**How can I give thickness to this line?** The thickness should only be in 2D. So in orthogonal bottom, top, left or right view the line should be invisible. Also, the corner in the line should be hard, not smooth.

extra question: how can I shape the ends of the line (rounded, squared etc.)?

[image]

Comment: Try a dedicated "Vector Software" like Illustrator or Inkscape ,they have options like line thickness and end types built into them.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/87254 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72423/how-to-import-svg-file-with-same-thickness/72430

Comment: @starzar The long segment should be able to rotate with the middle vertex as pivot point. That is hard to do if the whole thing is a fixed inkscape drawing. I could construct the line with two very narrow rectangles, overlapping at the pivot point. But then I don't need Inkscape for that, and the pivot point would look wrong anyways.

Comment: Hello :). You can select the edges, and extrude them along the Z axis to get a 2D thickness. Not the most elegant solution, but it works. And the middle corner will stay sharp.