# SVG contour style is missing

Tags: svg

I have this SVG I'm trying to import to blender, but the thickness of the contour just doesn't show.

Is there a way to import the svg exactly how is shown in the other softwares?

This r the prints of my problem.

[image: How the SVG should look like]

[image: How it looks when imported to Blender]

[image: How it looks when I render]

Comment: The first img is how the SVG should look like, the second is after importing to blender and the third is after I render it

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72423/how-to-import-svg-file-with-same-thickness/72430#72430

Comment: The line "thickness" is called the "stroke", that stroke is just an appearance applied to the vector line by the software (Inkscape or Illustrator). When you import an SVG into a 3d app, it only reads the base vector lines and doesn't translate that stroke width appearance to a 3d object. To get those lines, you need to edit the SVG in your vector program and outline the stroke before exporting.

Comment: Here's a article on how to outline a stroke in Illustrator: https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-outline-stroke-in-adobe-illustrator--cms-34160

Comment: .. or you could stroke the lines in Freestyle ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download, install and launch [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (an open source vector graphics editor), open your SVG, select all objects of the SVG file, ungroup a few times, go to *Path > Stroke to Path* , save the new SVG.

Import into Blender and you should see some more borders / lines.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It did the job. The colors of the SVG are all gone though, but that I can solve. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Blender 2.79.

Give the svg path a volume with the **Solidify** modifier.

Set the Offset to 0 and Use the Clamp value to thick or thin the stroke.

[image]